# Salesforce CPQ – How To Add Radio Buttons (Instead of Checkboxes) to Product Selection Screen?

Tags: cpq, quote, product, steelbrick, product-rule

#### In Salesforce CPQ, is it possible to limit the User to only allow them to select one Product via the Product Selection screen?

**1)** Instead of checkboxes, can we use radio buttons on the Product Selection screen instead?

This appears possible for Product Options on the *Configure Products* screen using the "Max Options" (SBQQ__MaxOptionCount__c) field on the Product Feature object:

> **Maximum Options**
>
> If a feature has a Max Options of 1, meaning your reps can only choose one option for that feature, CPQ is smart enough to show radio buttons instead of checkboxes. This makes it easier to switch between options (one click instead of two), while also giving the sales rep a visual cue about what they’re allowed to choose in the bundle.
>
> [image: Maximum Options Radio Buttons]
>
> https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/cpq-product-configuration/use-features-to-organize-options#maximum-options

... but this does not appear possible on the *Product Selection* screen.

**2)** If it is not possible to use radio buttons in this scenario, is it possible to use Product Rules to throw an error or warning if more than one Product is selected from the Product Selection screen?

This does not seem possible to me since Product Rules seem to be evaluated against Product Options (rather than Products) on the *Configure Products* screen:

> **Product Rules**
>
> You can evaluate a product option, quote, or a quote line against user-made conditions and perform an action in response.
>
> https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.cpq_product_rules.htm&type=5

[image: Product Selection Screen]

**3)** If both of these solutions are invalid, what would be the best way to accomplish this task?